# Why does gcc4 not unroll this loop?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, gcc4, loop-unrolling

In the `gcc 4.4.6` docs it is stated:

> ```
> -funroll-all-loops:
> Unroll all loops, even if their number of iterations is uncertain 
> when the loop isentered.
> ```

I am compiling this code:

```
int unroll(){
  int i = 0;
  int array[1000];
  do {
    use(i,array);
    i++;
  }while(i<1000);
  return(0);
}

void use(int i, int *array){
   int x = i*5;
   array[i] = x;
}
```

...once with the `funroll-all-loops` optimizations, once without:

```
OPT = -funroll-all-loops
NOOPT = -O0
```

Then I use `diff` to compare the assembly code of each (produced using `-S -fverbose-asm`).

The produced code is identical.

Tried changing the loop to a `do while`; 
adjusting the loop counter (up to 100);
changing the statements within the loop body.

What could I be missing? Why is this loop not being unrolled?

**Update**

[Nikos C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856199/nikos-c) suggested to raise the loop enroll parameter using `--param max-unroll-times=N` where N is the upper limit. 
While that was a sensible suggestion, it did not change behaviour. 
I also lowered the loop iterations to only 10. 
Also updated the code to actually 'do' something, no change.

Comment: `-O0` tells gcc not to apply any optimizations, which would include unrolling. Try `-O` or `-O2`.

Comment: I think the `NOOPT = -O0` indicates a control case (i.e., the one expected not to have unrolled loops).

Comment: yes that is done intentionally. NOOPT is the flag used to generate the assembly code for comparison w/o loop unrolling.

Comment: Try forcing the compiler to inline `use()`. There is generally no reason at all to unroll loops that have function calls.

Comment: Yet another `If I disable optimization, why doesn't gcc optimize?` question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have disabled all other optimizations in your "OPT" case, you tell to compiler to unroll all loops and then deny him the means to do so, like loop induction etc. Try

```
NOOPT = -O2
OPT = -O2 -funroll-all-loops
```

If I translate the snippet (changed slightly to an extern function to avoid any inlining and dead code elimination)

```
void use(int i, int *array);

int unroll(){
  int i = 0;
  int array[1000];
  do {
    use(i,array);
    i++;
  }while(i<1000);
  return(0);
}
```

with `gcc -O2  -funroll-all-loops test.c -o test2.o -c`, the resulting object code
is unrolled eight times:

```
  0000000000000000 <unroll>:
  0:   53                      push   %rbx
  1:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
  3:   48 81 ec a0 0f 00 00    sub    $0xfa0,%rsp
  a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  10:   89 df                   mov    %ebx,%edi
  12:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  15:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1a <unroll+0x1a>
  1a:   8d 7b 01                lea    0x1(%rbx),%edi
  1d:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  20:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  25 <unroll+0x25>
  25:   8d 7b 02                lea    0x2(%rbx),%edi
  28:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  2b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  30 <unroll+0x30>
  30:   8d 7b 03                lea    0x3(%rbx),%edi
  33:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  36:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  3b <unroll+0x3b>
  3b:   8d 7b 04                lea    0x4(%rbx),%edi
  3e:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  41:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  46 <unroll+0x46>
  46:   8d 7b 05                lea    0x5(%rbx),%edi
  49:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  4c:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  51 <unroll+0x51>
  51:   8d 7b 06                lea    0x6(%rbx),%edi
  54:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  57:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  5c <unroll+0x5c>
  5c:   8d 7b 07                lea    0x7(%rbx),%edi
  5f:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  62:   83 c3 08                add    $0x8,%ebx
  65:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  6a <unroll+0x6a>
  6a:   81 fb e8 03 00 00       cmp    $0x3e8,%ebx
  70:   75 9e                   jne    10 <unroll+0x10>
  72:   48 81 c4 a0 0f 00 00    add    $0xfa0,%rsp
  79:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  7b:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  7c:   c3                      retq
```